# vb.net webbrowser can't set value

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

here it's my HTML code

```
<input id="account_password" class="textInput" name="account.password" type="password" maxlength="30" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Minimum of 8 characters">
```

i've tried to set value using setattribute by value

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("account_password").SetAttribute("value", "Kemo2011")
```

the result

[image]

just the placeholder had changed + without passchar "****"

Comment: If you just type into that password text box does it show the `*`s?

Comment: yes it's shown as `***`s

Comment: Have you considered setting it via javascript instead? You know you can inject javascript programmatically from the web browser control.